# Visual Studio Folders in Project

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am currently trying to work myself into Visual Studio 2019. What I want is a clean structure between header and source files. My current project in the Solution Explorer looks like this:

```
--...
--References
--External Dependencies
--main.cpp
--Dummy.cpp
--Dummy.h
--...
```

What I want is a structure seen best in this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgVC4.gif)

```
--...
--References
--External Dependencies
--Header Files
---->Dummy.h
---->...
--Source Files
---->main.cpp
---->Dummy.cpp
---->...
--...
```

I don't know what this Function/Option needed here is called so searching this issue is not easy.

In most tutorials etc. I can find this kind of structure is set up automatically when they create a new solution/project. But not for me.

What is this I am looking for called? Can you point me to a source where I can read up on how to set this kind of thing up? Or even easier can you tell me how it's done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create folders in your project:

[image]

Create two folders named `Header_Files` and `Source_Files`:

[image]

Now you must set the extension filter:

[image]

That means: `.h` files will be systematically assigned to the folder `Header_Files`
Do the same thing with `Source_Files` by adding filter `cpp;cxx;c;...` which allows VS to assign systematically `.cpp;cxx;c;...` files to `Source_Files`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Worked just fine